# Search results not same when compared between desktop client and API

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

Okay, so I am searching for three hashtags '#data #visualization #nfl'. It works when done through browser but it doesn't when I am using Tweepy. It only works if I search for two hashtags. Either '#data #visualisation' or '#data #nfl'. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

A detailed reference on this API endpoint can be found at GET search/tweets.